# Plot Parametric f(x), inverse f(x) and f'(x) and then f(x)/f'(x) and inversef'(x)/inversef(x)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, inverse, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot  f(x), inverse f(x) and f'(x) and then f(x)/f'(x) and inversef'(x)/inversef(x)

f[x_] := 2 a ArcTanh[(# a)/Sqrt[-1 + #^2 b]] + a Log[1 + #^2 (a^2 - b)] - 2 Log[# b + Sqrt[-1 + #^2 b]] &[x] /. {a -> 0.2, b -> 0.3};

I don't know from where I can start?

Comment: Your function `f[x]` is complex, is this feature intended? If yes your question cann#t be answered.

Comment: Yes but I like to know inverse f(x) and its differential and their plots mostly.

Comment: Please clarify your question: You want to plot  parts of a complex function: `Re, Im, Abs,...`

Comment: Abs I would like to know Abs

Answer (score 2):

To plot `Abs[f[x]]==Sqrt[f[x] Conjugate[f[x]]` try

```
f = 2 a ArcTanh[(# a)/Sqrt[-1 + #^2 b]] + a Log[1 + #^2 (a^2 - b)] -2 Log[# b + Sqrt[-1 + #^2 b]] & /. {a -> 2/10, b -> 3/10};
Plot[Sqrt[f[x] Conjugate[f[x]]] , {x, -5, 5} , PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The inverse function of `Abs[f[x]]` is only defined in subintervalls `x<-2.17172,-2.17172<x<1.94146,x>1.94146`.

Comment: then I have this problem that how to introduce this f for plotting inversef'(x)/inversef(x)

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f = 2 a ArcTanh[(# a)/Sqrt[-1 + #^2 b]] + a Log[1 + #^2 (a^2 - b)] - 
     2 Log[# b + Sqrt[-1 + #^2 b]] & /. {a -> 2/10, b -> 3/10};

Plot[Abs[f[x]], {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "|f(x)|"}]
```

[image]

Use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to plot the inverse

```
ParametricPlot[{Abs[f[x]], x}, {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"|f(x)|", "x"}]
```

[image]

Use "Log" scaling ([`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html)) for the derivative

```
Plot[Abs[f'[x]], {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "|f'(x)|"},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

as well as for the ratio

```
Plot[Abs[f[x]/f'[x]], {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "|f(x)/f'(x)|"},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Comment: for plotting inverse f'(x)  /  inverse f(x) ??

Comment: The inverses are not well-defined since they are multi-valued. You could use `ParametricPlot` to plot `{Abs[f'[x]/f[x]], x}` or `{Log10[Abs[f'[x]/f[x]]], x}`